# How to open emulator shell from java code to determine system call events?

Tags: java, android, strace

I want to collect system call events to android applications with strace tool
First I lunch emulator then  I  write in terminal in linux the next command line :

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

After emulator shell I want to write strace command as shown in the picture:

[image: after emulator shell I want to write strace command as shown in the picture] from trminal it works fine with me but when I write java code

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -s emulator-5554 shell");
Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("strace -p 871");
```

It didn't work can any one help me to write this java code in eclipse 
please pay attention to the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `adb shell` command opens a new shell in which `strace`is executed. The Java version of your command executed both commands in the default shell. Hence you have to combine them:

`Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -s emulator-5554 shell strace -p 871");`

Comment: I really don't know how can I thank you. It works with me

Comment: On Stackoverflow you should mark the question that solves your question with the green check mark on the left side.

Comment: on the left side beside my answer

Comment: Thanks Robert  i did it